# User Control Anchor not working

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a `User Control` that contains a number of other controls. I want my User Control to resize itself properly as the user resizes the parent form.

I have set the `AutoSize` property of this User Control to `true`.

Even though I have set the `Anchor` property of all the controls inside my User Control, it is the User Control itself that

1. Does not have an Anchor property in its Property menu in Designer
2. Behaves very strangely when I add its Anchor property manually in the its `InitializeComponent()` method (Visual Studio automatically removes the line from the Designer code and from then my User Control gets dragged to the bottom right of the designer)

How can I set my User Control so that it gets resized as the user changes the size of the form?

Comment: Are you looking for the `Anchor` property when designing the UC or after you have placed your UC onto a form/other control?

Comment: @BerndLinde After. I have used my UC for a while, now I am adding resizability feature to my Winform application.

Comment: From what base are you inheriting? All my UserControls that inherit from `UserControl` have the `Anchor` property at designtime.

Comment: @BerndLinde Then there should be something wrong with my VS. I just don't know why the line vanishes from my *Designer.cs* as I build and run my project.

Comment: That would be because VS generates the code in Designer.cs, replacing any custom changes made. Rather find why the property is not available

Comment: `UserControls` do not have an accessible `Anchor` property until you create an instance of it. But you can set it in their constructor. Note that this should be done __after__ the `InitializeComponent` call, __not in__ it and that it doesn't __create__ the property but __sets__ it.

Comment: @TaW I made some good progress thanks to your good point. However, the problem I have now is that the UC size remains the same even if I set the Anchor to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`. I have set the anchors for controls inside the UC but it's the UC itself that remains at the same size. Its `AutoSize`is set *true* by the way.

Comment: Is the UC sitting dierectly on the form or is there one or more other controls between?

Comment: @TaW it's sitting inside a TabPage control actually.

Comment: So, is the Tab resizing correctly?

Comment: @TaW I suppose so, yes. I put another button on one of TabPage's corners in addition to the UC and the button seems to be following its anchor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100216/discussion-between-taw-and-disasterkid).

Comment: @TaW Oh I'm so sorry I became unavailable. It would be very kind of you if you had time now.

Comment: @TaW Ok I fixed the problem by adding the line `this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` at the end of my constructor. Still wondering why my UC's property box has no *Anchor* and *Dock* properties. Idk if I should add this as an answer or you going to do that? Thanks for your help regardless.

Comment: I guess the properties are hidden as long as there is no parent, as they only make sense in combination. Using Fill is one option but setting all anchors should work just as well and will let you add stuff arounf the UC. Go ahead and write an answer.. I don't feel like it atm :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Dock` and `Anchor` properties are hidden from the designer of the `UserControl`. They are only availbly once an instance has been added to some  parent.

However they do exist and can be set, for example in the constructor:

```
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```